# How can you write multiple statements in elisp 'if' statement?

Tags: syntax, elisp

In elisp, there is an 'if' case where I would like to perform many different things:

```
(if condition
    (do-something)
    (do-another-thing)
    ...)
```

However, (do-another-thing) is executed in the else-case only.  How can you specify a block of instructions to execute?  For example:

```
(if condition
    (begin
        (do-something)
        (do-another-thing)
        ...))
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Use `progn`:

```
(if condition
    (progn
        (do-something)
        (do-another-thing)))
```

See [sequencing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequencing.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 54):

If there's no `else` required, it might be more readable to use:

```
(when condition
    (do-something)
    (do-another-thing))
```

And, there's the converse

```
(unless (not condition)
    (do-something)
    (do-another-thing))
```

Check out the [Emacs Lisp manual for conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html).

Comment: FWIW, I generally follow the convention suggested in *Common Lisp The Language* of using `when` and `unless` when the return value is not important (i.e., they are used for side effects only). I generally use `and` and `or` when the return value is important. I generally use `if` and `cond` when there are multiple branches (whether or not the return value is important).