# How to determine operating system in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

How do I programmatically determine which OS Emacs is running under in ELisp?

I would like to run different code in `.emacs` depending on the OS.

Comment: From GNU Emacs Lisp reference manual
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The `system-type` variable:

```
system-type is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is darwin

Documentation:
Value is symbol indicating type of operating system you are using.
Special values:
  `gnu'         compiled for a GNU Hurd system.
  `gnu/linux'   compiled for a GNU/Linux system.
  `darwin'      compiled for Darwin (GNU-Darwin, Mac OS X, ...).
  `ms-dos'      compiled as an MS-DOS application.
  `windows-nt'  compiled as a native W32 application.
  `cygwin'      compiled using the Cygwin library.
Anything else indicates some sort of Unix system.
```

Answer (score 97):

For folks newer to elisp, a sample usage:

```lisp
(if (eq system-type 'darwin)
  ; something for OS X if true
  ; optional something if not
)
```

Or, if we don't care for the *else-form* and have multiple *then-forms*,

```lisp
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  ; do this
  ; and this ...
)
```

Comment: OK, I burned myself several times with weird branch blocks in Elisp (if- and else-part separated by a newline, `progn` necessary for blocks), so a recommendation to everyone not familiar with the quirks - check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/912397/544059) out.

Comment: @kermit666 actually `progn` isn't needed if you don't have an else case. What I mean by that is that you can just use `when` instead of `if`, which is equivalent to `(if ... (progn ...) '())`

Comment: Upvoted because I was trying to use "=" and it wasn't working.

Comment: @metakermit you can use `cond` like so: `(case system-type
   ((gnu/linux) "notify-send")
   ((darwin) "growlnotify -a Emacs.app -m"))`

Comment: I meant `case`, not `cond`. `case` works since `system-type` is a symbol like `'gnu/linux` or `darwin`, not a string

Comment: I read somewhere that in emacs `eq` is not same with `equal`, and `equal` works better in general comparing stuffs.

Comment: @SdSaati In this case, `eq` works as intended. How could it "work better" here?

Comment: Note to the OP: With a single branch, one can use `when`.

Answer (score 27):

I created a simple macro to easily run code depending on the system-type:

```
(defmacro with-system (type &rest body)
  "Evaluate BODY if `system-type' equals TYPE."
  (declare (indent defun))
  `(when (eq system-type ',type)
     ,@body))

(with-system gnu/linux
  (message "Free as in Beer")
  (message "Free as in Freedom!"))
```

Answer (score 11):

In a .emacs, there is not only the `system-type`, but also the `window-system` variable.
This is useful when you want to choose between some x only option, or a terminal, or macos setting.

Answer (score 7):

Now there is also Linux Subsystem for Windows (bash under Windows 10) where `system-type` is `gnu/linux`. To detect this system type use:

```
(if
    (string-match "Microsoft"
         (with-temp-buffer (shell-command "uname -r" t)
                           (goto-char (point-max))
                           (delete-char -1)
                           (buffer-string)))
    (message "Running under Linux subsystem for Windows")
    (message "Not running under Linux subsystem for Windows")
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly already answered, but for those interested, I just tested this on FreeBSD and there the reported value was "berkeley-unix".

Answer (score 0):

There's also (in versions 24-26 at least) `system-configuration`, if you want to adjust for differences in build system. However, the documentation of this variable does not describe the possible vales that it may contain like the documentation of the  `system-type` variable does.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to do a pattern match on the `system-type` variable, like this:

```
(pcase system-type
  ;; GNU/Linux or WSL
  (gnu/linux
   (message "This is GNU/Linux"))

  ;; macOS
  (darwin
   (message "This is macOS"))

  ;; Windows
  (windows-nt
   (message "This is Windows")) 

  ;; BSDs
  (berkeley-unix
    (message "This is a BSD"))

  ;; Other operating system
  (_
   (message "Unknown operating system")))
```

For more information, and additional types of operating systems, see the full documentation on `system-type` in https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/System-Environment.html

(An easy way to test the above code is to paste it in your *scratch* buffer and press C-j after the outermost parenthesis)