# Different setup in .emacs for PC/Mac

Tags: emacs

I need to have different setup in .emacs depending on my system (Mac or PC).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817257/how-to-determine-operating-system-in-elisp) teaches how to know the system that my emacs is running.

- How can I check the variable 'system-type' is to set what in emacs?
- What code should I have in .emacs to have different setup for PC and Mac?

```
???
(when (eq system-type 'windows-nt') 
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(if (equal system-type 'windows-nt)
    (progn
         (... various windows-nt stuff ...)))
(if (equal system-type 'darwin)
    (progn
         (... various mac stuff ...)))
```

What I do in my .emacs is set a variable (I call it this-config) based on machine type and name. Then I use the same .emacs everywhere.

Using this code, I can pull the machine name out:

```
(defvar this-machine "default")
(if (getenv "HOST")
    (setq this-machine (getenv "HOST")))
(if (string-match "default" this-machine)
    (if (getenv "HOSTNAME")
        (setq this-machine (getenv "HOSTNAME"))))
(if (string-match "default" this-machine)
    (setq this-machine system-name))
```

You can then set this-config based on system-type and/or machine name.

Then I use this code:

```
(cond ((or (equal this-machine "machineX")
           (equal this-machine "machineY"))
       (do some setup for machineX and machineY))
```

Edit: `system-type` returns a symbol, not a string

Answer (score 1):

My emacs says darwin, which is the name for the open OS that OSX is built on. To see the values do a describe-variable on system-type.

Note that the mac also has several possible window types so you might need to make more decisions.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
(if (eq window-system 'w32)
    (progn
... your functions here for Microsoft Windows ...
))
```

`window-system` is a function and returns the name of the window system.

`system-type` is a variable. Do <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> `system-type` <kbd>RET</kbd> to have the list of supported system-types for your case :

From the help :

> ```
>   `gnu'          compiled for a GNU Hurd system.
>   `gnu/linux'    compiled for a GNU/Linux system.
>   `gnu/kfreebsd' compiled for a GNU system with a FreeBSD kernel.
>   `darwin'       compiled for Darwin (GNU-Darwin, Mac OS X, ...).
>   `ms-dos'       compiled as an MS-DOS application.
>   `windows-nt'   compiled as a native W32 application.
>   `cygwin'       compiled using the Cygwin library.
> Anything else (in Emacs 23.1, the possibilities are: aix, berkeley-unix,
> hpux, irix, lynxos 3.0.1, usg-unix-v) indicates some sort of
> Unix system.
> ```