# Is there a way to detect which platform we are in it, inside .spacemacs file?

Tags: linux, windows, editor, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs and I want to declare **different paths** for org-mode **according to the platform** that I'm inside it.

For example, if I'm in Linux, I want the path be `~/orgs` but if I was in windows the path should be `D:\orgs\`.

**Is there a variable to check the current platform?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817257/how-to-determine-operating-system-in-elisp

Comment: Thank you @dalanicolai please post this as an answer, to check it as the correct one.

Comment: Well, an answer should be complete, not just a link, and I am not sure if I should copy the answer from there. I think the link in the comment works okay already.

There is an [Emacs stack-exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) b.t.w., I guess it would be better to ask these questions there. Or on the Spacemacs gitter, but you have found that already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions(Thanks to @dalanicolai and @milochadam in the gitter website of spacemacs for all of the helps) is that You **declare your condition inside** `user-init ()`
for example, I declared two global variables: `snippet_path` and `org_path` and they will get different values depends on the platform(Linux/windows):

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-init ()
;; ... other stuff

(if (or (equal system-type 'cygwin) (equal system-type 'windows-nt) (equal system-type 'ms-dos))
    ;; if we are in windows
      (progn
        (setq snippet_path "e:/home/snippets")
        (setq org_path "d:/org-mode/todo.org")
      )
    ;; else if (we are in linux)
      (progn
        (setq snippet_path "/home/ghost/spacemacs/snippets")
        (setq org_path "d:/org-mode/todo.org")
      )
  )

;; ... other stuff
)
```

Now we can use these two variables everywhere we like, for example inside our layer configs:

```lisp
(auto-completion :variables                      
                  auto-completion-private-snippets-directory snippet_path
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the command

> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
> Will return the OS name and version. Put that in variable after running the command and then do some comparison tests.

see this link:
https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-windows-os-version-from-command/

Comment: Thank you @Eoin for the response, this seems to work just in windows, not other OS.